# SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, unrecognized token ""

Tags: php, search

I am trying to create a PHP search query that searches by each word from the database. But i get this error when search query is submitted.

> Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, unrecognized token: "'%export%" in C:\xampp\htdocs\xport\searchresult.php on line 107

Below is my code.

For the search page

```
if (isset($_POST['mainSearch'])) 
{

if (!empty($_POST['mainSearch']))
{
    $searchquery = $_POST['mainSearch'];

    $query = str_replace(" ", "+", $_POST['mainSearch']);
    header("Location: searchresult.php?mainSearch=" . $query);

}

}
```

Page to display search result.

```
if (isset($_GET["mainSearch"])) 
{
  $condition = '';
  $query = explode(" ", $_GET['mainSearch']);

  foreach ($query as $text) 
  {
      $condition .= "question LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($text)."%' OR answer LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($text)."%'";
  }
  $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);

  $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE " . $condition;
  $result = $db->query($sql_query);

  if ($result)
  {
      while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
      {
           echo '<div class="quesbox_2">
            <div class="questitle">
                <h2>'.$row["question"].'</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="quesanswer">'.$row["answer"].'</div>
        </div>';
      }
  }
  else
  {

  }
  }
```

What is the reason for this error. I think its because the string is not properly escaped, if this is the reason how do i `mysqli_real_escape_string()` in `SQLite3` (this is the database i am using). If not, Please how do i fix this.

Comment: That isn't a prepared statement. You're still concatenating the value.

Comment: I would hazzard a guess that `$condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);` is chopping off 4 characters of useful Where Condition

Comment: If you echo out the query you'll see you're missing some spaces between things that you need. If you have more than one condition you'll end up with `%"condition`

Comment: Maybe if you added some error processing code, the system would give you some useful clue's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way if you are trying to search by each word

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["mainSearch"])) 
{
  $condition = '';
  $query = explode(" ", $_GET["mainSearch"]);

  foreach ($query as $text) 
  {
      //change condition query
      $condition .= "question LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($text)."%' OR ";
  }
  $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);


  $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE " . $condition;
  $sql_query_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM questions WHERE " . $condition;
  $result = $db->query($sql_query);

  //count query result to display something else if no records where found.
  $resultCount = $db->querySingle($sql_query_count);

  if ($resultCount > 0)
  {
  if ($result)
  {
      while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
      {
           echo '<div class="quesbox_3">
            <div class="questitle">
                <h2>'.$row["question"].'</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="quesanswer">'.$row["answer"].'</div>
        </div>';
      }
  }
  }
  else
  {
      echo "No results found";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the number of substring to `-3`.
So change

```
$condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);
```

to the new

```
$condition = substr($condition, 0, -3);
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need an `OR` condition in your `WHERE` clause that will fetch all results matching any of the words. Just add `OR` at the end of your query part and you should be fine.

```
foreach ($query as $text) 
{
    $condition .= "question LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($text)."%' OR answer LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($text)."%' OR ";
}
// Will chop 4 characters ' OR ' from end of the string
$condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);
```

To make it little clean, you can escapeString once when retrieved from the parameter to avoid escaping it again and again in the loop.

```
$mainSearch = SQLite3::escapeString($_GET['mainSearch']);
$query = explode(" ", $mainSearch);

foreach ($query as $text) 
{
    $condition .= "question LIKE '%$text%' OR answer LIKE '%$text%' OR ";
}
// Will chop 4 characters ' OR ' from end of the string
$condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);
```

Comment: What happens when you loop more than once through the `foreach()`? The concatenation has no spaces in it and will generate a query with syntax errors. `'%"question`

Comment: Have already added space at the end of string `[space]OR[space]`. It won't break.